# DES_DECRYPT & DES_ENCRYPT : MySql & phpMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an issue using `DES_DECRYPT` & `DES_ENCRYPT` in MySQL.

When I run the following select clause in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT DES_DECRYPT(DES_ENCRYPT('mytext','mypassword'),'mypassword');
```

It returns

> DES_DECRYPT(DES_ENCRYPT('mytext','mypassword'),'mypassword')
>   6d7974657874

Normally it should return mytext again, right?

When I run it inside php, it works like a charm. Anyone knows what I did wrong here ?

[External link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/encryption-and-compression-functions/des_decrypt%28%29.php)

Comment: @RobertRozas: What's wrong with phpMyAdmin?  Though, this HeidiSQL does look pretty cool.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, there is nothing wrong with phpMyAdmin

Comment: **Why** are you using DES encryption? It's [crackable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212563/time-to-crack-des-is-it-a-task-suitable-for-a-script-kiddie-yet).

Comment: @tadam: This is just for testing purpose

Comment: I hope you're not intending to encrypt passwords with it.

Comment: @tadam nop, this is just to restrict users to browse all the content by changing the id in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here:

```
mysql> select des_decrypt(des_encrypt('foo', 'bar'), 'bar');
+-----------------------------------------------+
| des_decrypt(des_encrypt('foo', 'bar'), 'bar') |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| foo                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which version of MySQL are you using, and how are you running the query/displaying the results?

Comment: Hi Marc.. Thanks for your answer ! but that's the printscreen when I run the query on phpmyadmin.. http://s27.postimg.org/3khvag1o3/des_DECRYPT.png

Comment: odd. des-crypted data is basically random ascii garbage. you're getting back what looks like a hex result.

Comment: @MarcB: phpMyAdmin has an option to display hex instead of random binary garbage :-)

Answer (score 0):

All right I have the answer, thanks Marc B. 
This is just an option in php myadmin. See screenshot: http://s2.postimg.org/iatjf29fd/des_DECRYPT.png

Thanks for the support !!

Comment: unfortunately the link is dead.